# Is the GoogleAppEngine dev server implementation of Task Queues different to production?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

I have mocked-up a tool I would like to use to automate some of our back-of-house tasks. It implements task queues somewhat, but I have a quick question. The Dev environment seems to operate as a single task-queue with a bucket size of 1 no matter how many named queues there are.

Is the production (cloud) deployed implementation of Task Queues different as described. The performance running locally on the AppEngineLauncher is a little disappointing but perhaps it runs bucket size = 1 as a deliberate limitation?﻿

Comment: You can not derive any performance data from the dev server and apply it to production for any metric you care to observe.  dev is an approximation at best and has none of the production performance characteristics nor it's scalability

Comment: This I understand - it's hard to pin down much in the way of specifics. Essentially it runs single bucketed single threaded. I will deploy and test and hope instance hours don't cost me an arm and a leg.